# Business Object - Void Data Provider

Tags: business-objects

I am creating a BO report with six data providers.
For Some reasons, there is a ghost data provider appears in the Report Manager which has  same name as one other data provider but it has no objects in it.

I couldn't able to edit/delete this data provider(ghost) as it is not appearing in the data manager.

Any suggestion, for deleting this  data provider(ghost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, it got resolved.

What I did is,

I right clicked on the data provider,which is just below this dataprovider(ghost),

I clicked edit data provider, which ends up in a new query panel with no objects in it, however I expected some objects in it.

So, I added a object and saved the query. And Now, the Ghost Data provider name got changed to (Query 10), and also, starts appearing in the data manager.

Seems like a wierd bug.